# Using LibTiff in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, libtiff

I'm trying to use LibTiff in a C++ Program in Visual Studio 2010. I downloaded tiff-3.9.2.zip from ftp://ftp.remotesensing.org/pub/libtiff. To test LibTiff it would be nice if someone could give me a step by step instruction how to import libtiff to visual Studio and build the Fax2Tiff tool.

There are so many files so that I am totally confused.

What I already have done:

1) Created a new Empty Win32 Console Application Project named "TiffTest"

2) Copied the folder "libtiff" from the tiff-3.9.2.zip to the Project Folder

3) Copied the file "fax2tiff.c" to the Project Folder

4) Added those files to the Project

[image][image]

5) Added the "libtiff" folter to the additional include folders

6) Renamed the files "tif_config.vc.h" and "tiffconf.vc.h" to "tif_config.h" and "tiffconf.h"

7) Tried to compile it.

This does not really work. All I do to get rid of the error messages causes new error messages. Can anyone tell me how I can get libtiff to work?

I really need help...

Thank you so much!

Comment: You might be better off downloading the binaries? Have you tried this link - there's some installation instructions too: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/tiff.htm

Comment: Next time make a screen shot of the Error list.

Comment: If you only need the basics of libtiff you can use the package from nuget! This make the start more easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be better

- to build libtiff as a static library.
- to build fax2tiff as a console application that links with the library

In addition, you should decide which version of the file- and memory-related files you want to use in your version of the library. There are Unix, DOS and Windows-style versions for file- and memory related files.

And for fax2tiff you will probably need Windows version of the `getopt.c` and `getopt.h` files. You may use `wingetopt.h` and `wingetopt.c` [found on koders.com](http://koders.com/default.aspx?s=wingetopt&search.x=0&search.y=0&la=%2a&li=%2a&scope=)

I successfully use libtiff-3.9.4 and tiff2pdf built using this approach.

Btw, libtiff version 3.9.4 is most recent one in 3.x branch.

Below is the part of my `LibTiff.vcxproj`. It shows which files are needed to build libtiff on Windows using Visual Studio 2010.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="t4.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="tiff.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="tiffconf.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="tiffio.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="tiffiop.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="tiffvers.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="tif_config.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="tif_dir.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="tif_fax3.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="tif_predict.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="uvcode.h" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="tif_aux.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_close.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_codec.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_color.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_compress.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_dir.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_dirinfo.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_dirread.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_dirwrite.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_dumpmode.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_error.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_extension.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_fax3.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_fax3sm.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_flush.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_getimage.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_jbig.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_jpeg.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_luv.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_lzw.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_next.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_ojpeg.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_open.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_packbits.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_pixarlog.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_predict.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_print.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_read.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_strip.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_swab.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_thunder.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_tile.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_unix.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_version.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_warning.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_write.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tif_zip.c" />
```