# Read TIFF image using LibHaru

Tags: tiff, libharu

I need load an image in TIFF format and export it to a PDF file using the C++ library of LibHaru. Is there a way to load TIFF images using LibHaru? If not, what other option do I have?

Comment: Does this library support loading TIFFs? From the description it's about exporting to PDF, so you'll probably need to use a different library to load and convert the file to what libHaru expects.

Comment: That is actually the question. I'm sorry, I wasn't so accurate. I do not know if LibHaru can load TIFF images.

Comment: Well the way it's phrased - "using LibHaru" you imply you want to use LibHaru - and LibHaru only - to load the file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647791/using-libtiff-in-visual-studio-2010